# Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (0)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sent data to the server database, i implement it using wamp server it was working fine but when i installed the db on my domain and switched it to my domain its giving the following error.

I have kept my files inside a folder in root directory

Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (0)

Below is my config file i am using to connect to the db

```
<?php
 // Database configuration
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxx');
    define('DB_HOST', '192.210.195.245');
    define('DB_NAME', 'tabanico_userlogin');
?>
```

here my code connecting db, config.php file contains the code pasted above

```
<?php
class DbConnect {  
        private $conn;        
        function __construct() {        
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
        }        
        function __destruct() {        
        $this->close();
        }        
        function connect() {        
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';                  
        $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());         
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());        
        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;
        }        
         // Close function          
        function close() {
        // close db connection
        mysql_close($this->conn);
        }
}
?>
```

and my file receiving data

```
<?php
include_once './DbConnect.php';
function createNewPrediction() {

        $response = array();
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

        $db = new DbConnect();
       // mysql query
        $query = "INSERT INTO login(id,name,email,password) VALUES('$id','$name','$email','$password')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if ($result) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Prediction added successfully!";
        } else {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Failed to add prediction!";
        }
       // echo json response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
createNewPrediction();
?>
```

I have seen related post but didn't find useful answers. Can anyone help me in getting out of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and where is the rest of your code? I can't see this failing, other than the fact that you may have quoted your constants in your query.

Comment: you're not using 000webhost by any chance are you (or other similar)? In trying to connect to a remote server without having paid for it.

Comment: the code is working fine , i tested it using wamp server, its giving error when i tried it testing on domain, so I dont think I have to upload the rest of the code. btw thanks for your time.

Comment: someone gave you an answer below. I am passing on this question.

Comment: so you mean I have to use my domain name in DB_HOST like
define('DB_HOST', 'www.abc.com');

Comment: post the db connection part of the code. Some glitches works fine in local but not in live environment

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code where you try to connect to the server. I guess you tried to connect using the following function:

`mysql_connect('DB_HOST', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD');`

Since you defined the host using `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`, you do not have to use apostrophes. `DB_HOST` is a constant here. So try to use to

`mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);`

instead. If you use apostrophes like in `'DB_HOST'`, it is interpreted as a string instead of the value of the constant `DB_HOST` containing `localhost`. That's a possible reason why you get the error that `DB_HOST` is an unknown host.

But please post the connection part of your code to see if that's really the mistake.